# Database driven CSS Menu helper

Tags: asp.net, css

We need a **database driven CSS menu**. How would you do that?

I already managed to get a database driven menu working using ASP.NET Menu and an XSLT file to parse an XML string that resulted from a DataSet object.

It works fine, but we don't want to use JavaScript (generated by the ASP.NET Menu) or XSLT because the (X)HTML that results is not saved to search engines.

Would you suggest a menu helper to create an unordered list?

Should I parse the XML or use the DataSet object to do it?

Or do you have another suggestion?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up chossing this option:
http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/latest-flyout.html

It's very simple. Don't forget to donate to the guy.

And of course, before I use this I had to generate an unordered list with others nested in it and I did it with a menu helper I created.

Thank you all for all your terrific answers! :D

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://dotnetslackers.com/VB_NET/re-17169_Rendering_a_databound_UL_menu.aspx

Comment: I ended up using another solution before I saw your answer but that seems a good alternative though. Thank you, Mark, for answering this question.